# JavaFX 8 - Layout swapping or similar/equivalent functionality to Qt's StackedWidget?

Tags: java, qt, layout, awt, javafx-8

I've been asked to write a conversion program in JavaFX, but i need to allow the user to set different options depending on the conversion direction.

In reaction to swapping the conversion direction, I need to show two different (unique) sets of controls for options relating to the current direction only.

In one direction I need to display two TextFields, in the other direction, a pair of RadioButtons. I could show both at the same time and just enable/disable when needed, but I'm trying for a less cluttered approach first.

I'm looking for a solution that has similar layout-switching functionality to Qt's StackedWidget that I've used in C++, so i can swap out the TextFields for the RadioButtons and vice versa depending on the conversion direction.

It's important to note that this window has many other options that are common to both directions, so it's only a small part that needs to change according to the conversion direction. Thus I'd prefer it if I could easily access the swapped controls from within the same controller.

I don't want tabs or page numbers as the user controls the direction elsewhere, so TabPane and Pagination are out, unless those undesirable pieces of functionality can be disabled.

I've heard that there's something called a CardLayout in another Java framework (it's in awt if i heard right) which would do the job I want, what's the JavaFX 8 equivalent? Or is there another solution that i should be using instead?

I'm using SceneBuilder so ideally something i can implement in that, but I can use pure code if need be.

Comment: Just use any `Pane` subclass, and call `pane.getChildren().setAll(textFieldDisplay);` or `pane.getChildren().setAll(radioButtonDisplay);` as required. `setAll(...)` will replace all the content of the pane.

Comment: @James_D Not sure i follow. I'm relatively new to JavaFX. I can see you're swapping them but how would I create `radioButtonDisplay` and `textFieldDisplay` and of what type?

Comment: They can be any `Node` type you need them to be, `setAll(...)` will just take a collection of `Node` objects (a collection of size 1 in this case). You can create them any way you want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any `Pane` subclass (e.g. a `StackPane`) and call `pane.getChildren().setAll(textFieldDisplay);` or `pane.getChildren().setAll(radioButtonDisplay);` as needed. The different displays can be any kind of `Node`, but since they hold other controls they would typically also be some subclass of `Pane`. In the example below I use a `GridPane` for one and a `VBox` for the other. In a real application, you might define each one in its own FXML file and load them independently, etc.

Complete example (using FXML):

Main.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>  

<VBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.MainController"
    alignment="CENTER">

    <padding>
        <Insets top="20" left="20" right="20" bottom="20" />
    </padding>

    <CheckBox text="Show Text Fields" fx:id="showTextFields" VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
        <VBox.margin>
            <Insets top="10" left="10" right="10" bottom="10"/>
        </VBox.margin>
    </CheckBox>
    <StackPane fx:id="display" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />

    <Button  text="OK" onAction="#submit" VBox.vgrow="NEVER" />
</VBox>
```

MainController.java:

```
package application;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

public class MainController {
    @FXML
    private CheckBox showTextFields ;
    @FXML
    private StackPane display ;

    private Node radioDisplay ;
    private Node textFieldDisplay ;

    private RadioButtonController radioButtonController ;
    private TextFieldController textFieldController ;

    public void initialize() throws Exception {

        FXMLLoader radioDisplayLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("RadioDisplay.fxml"));
        radioDisplay = radioDisplayLoader.load();
        radioButtonController = radioDisplayLoader.getController();

        FXMLLoader textFieldDisplayLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("TextFieldDisplay.fxml"));
        textFieldDisplay = textFieldDisplayLoader.load();
        textFieldController = textFieldDisplayLoader.getController();

        showTextFields.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, wasSelected, isSelected) -> {
            if (isSelected) {
                display.getChildren().setAll(textFieldDisplay);
            } else {
                display.getChildren().setAll(radioDisplay);
            }
        });

        display.getChildren().add(radioDisplay);
    }

    @FXML
    private void submit() {
        if (showTextFields.isSelected()) {
            System.out.println("Value 1 is "+ textFieldController.getText1());
            System.out.println("Value 2 is "+ textFieldController.getText2());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Chosen value is "+radioButtonController.getSelectedItem());
        }
    }
}
```

RadioDisplay.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton?>

<VBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.RadioButtonController"
    alignment="TOP_CENTER" spacing="10">

    <padding>
        <Insets top="10" left="10" right="10" bottom="10"/>
    </padding>

    <RadioButton text="Choice 1" selected="true" fx:id="choice1"/>
    <RadioButton text="Choice 2" fx:id="choice2"/>
</VBox>
```

RadioButtonController.java:

```
package application;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;

public class RadioButtonController {
    @FXML
    private RadioButton choice1 ;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton choice2 ;

    public void initialize() {

        ToggleGroup toggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();
        choice1.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);
        choice2.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);
    }

    public String getSelectedItem() {
        if (choice1.isSelected()) {
            return "Choice 1";
        } else if (choice2.isSelected()) {
            return "Choice 2";
        } else return "" ;
    }
}
```

TextFieldDisplay.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>

<GridPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.TextFieldController"
    hgap="10" vgap="10">

    <columnConstraints>
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="NEVER" halignment="RIGHT"/>
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    </columnConstraints>

    <Label text="Value 1:" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0"/>
    <Label text="Value 2:" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>

    <TextField fx:id="textField1" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="0"/>
    <TextField fx:id="textField2" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>

</GridPane>
```

TextFieldController.java:

```
package application;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class TextFieldController {
    @FXML
    private TextField textField1 ;
    @FXML
    private TextField textField2 ;

    public String getText1() {
        return textField1.getText() ;
    }
    public String getText2() {
        return textField2.getText();
    }
}
```

Main.java:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        VBox root = (VBox)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

All the FXML files are in the same package (`application`) as the .java files.

**Update**

If you prefer not to "modularize" it to this extent, you can put everything in a single FXML with a single controller. In that case, Main.fxml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>  
<?import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>

<VBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.MainController"
    alignment="CENTER">

    <padding>
        <Insets top="20" left="20" right="20" bottom="20" />
    </padding>

    <CheckBox text="Show Text Fields" fx:id="showTextFields" VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
        <VBox.margin>
            <Insets top="10" left="10" right="10" bottom="10"/>
        </VBox.margin>
    </CheckBox>
    <StackPane fx:id="display" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
        <VBox fx:id="radioDisplay" alignment="TOP_CENTER" spacing="10">

            <padding>
                <Insets top="10" left="10" right="10" bottom="10" />
            </padding>

            <RadioButton text="Choice 1" selected="true" fx:id="choice1" />
            <RadioButton text="Choice 2" fx:id="choice2" />
        </VBox>

        <fx:define>
            <GridPane fx:id="textFieldDisplay" hgap="10" vgap="10">

                <columnConstraints>
                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="NEVER" halignment="RIGHT" />
                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                </columnConstraints>

                <Label text="Value 1:" GridPane.columnIndex="0"
                    GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
                <Label text="Value 2:" GridPane.columnIndex="0"
                    GridPane.rowIndex="1" />

                <TextField fx:id="textField1" GridPane.columnIndex="1"
                    GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
                <TextField fx:id="textField2" GridPane.columnIndex="1"
                    GridPane.rowIndex="1" />

            </GridPane>
        </fx:define>
    </StackPane>

    <Button  text="OK" onAction="#submit" VBox.vgrow="NEVER" />
</VBox>
```

and the corresponding controller is

```
package application;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

public class MainController {
    @FXML
    private CheckBox showTextFields ;
    @FXML
    private StackPane display ;

    @FXML
    private Node radioDisplay ;
    @FXML
    private Node textFieldDisplay ;

    @FXML
    private TextField textField1 ;
    @FXML
    private TextField textField2 ;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton choice1 ;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton choice2 ;

    public void initialize() throws Exception {

        showTextFields.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, wasSelected, isSelected) -> {
            if (isSelected) {
                display.getChildren().setAll(textFieldDisplay);
            } else {
                display.getChildren().setAll(radioDisplay);
            }
        });

        ToggleGroup toggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();
        choice1.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);
        choice2.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);
    }

    @FXML
    private void submit() {
        if (showTextFields.isSelected()) {
            System.out.println("Value 1 is "+ textField1.getText());
            System.out.println("Value 2 is "+ textField2.getText());
        } else {
            String chosenValue ;
            if (choice1.isSelected()) {
                chosenValue = "Choice 1";
            } else if (choice2.isSelected()) {
                chosenValue = "Choice 2";
            } else {
                chosenValue

 = "None";
            }

            System.out.println("Chosen value is "+chosenValue);
        }
    }
}
```

(and in this case, remove the other two FXML files and their controllers).

Comment: This looks like it would be an absolute pain to do. I'm trying to keep all the UI in FXML so would need to create them, but can't quite get my head around how I would attach the controller to them, unless i can attach one controller to many FXML files. (As i said, I'm new to FX).

Comment: If you use multiple FXML files, just use a different controller for each.

Comment: That's going to complicate matters as i need to grab the input in the same function as the rest of the controls. This is just a small part of a larger window, and it literally hinges on an IF:
if the conversion is A->B, query the text fields and use that with the other inputs.
if the conversion is B->A, query the radiobuttons and use that with the other inputs.

Comment: This is why adding more controllers would complicate matters i think, but then this may be me misunderstanding how to use the FXML in the way you mean. It just seems silly that I'd have to write two more objects just to grab the inputs from four controls.
I have a controller that grabs the other inputs, can't that also be hooked into the FXML files I'm swapping?

Comment: Updated example to use FXML. (There are plenty of other ways to do it, this is just one of them.)

Comment: Sorry, I was assuming you wanted it broken down into components like that. If you prefer, you can just do the whole thing in one FXML file and use a single controller. Just use a [`<fx:define>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#define_elements) for the piece(s) not shown at startup.

Comment: My fault for not being clear. Thanks for the pointers, I may end up using the multi-object approach if that's easier, but I'll look into <fx:define> if that will reduce the need for little-used classes. At the moment I'm using SceneBuilder to produce the FXML as I'm not quite used to some of the ways FX lays things out yet, so not sure how I'd get it to put a <fx:define> in. The sizings have been the biggest headache, which is why I've been creating using WYSIWYG rather than type XML manually

Comment: Updated with the example refactored to a single FXML. I don't think SceneBuilder currently supports `<fx:define>`, which is (imo) a big drawback. But you can always create that part in a separate FXML file in SceneBuilder, then edit the FXML files afterwards.

Comment: Now that makes sense! I was wondering how I would grab the defined object in the code, i didn't realise that my `@FXML` declarations and binding them to controls was adding the `fx:id` attribute. Shows I hadn't looked at the FXML much.

Both are currently in the same file, I'm just enabling and disabling as required, but now I just need to wrap one in `<fx:define>` tags. Coolio!